# Indeterminations and Comparison Test for Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be a divergent series with $a_n > 0$ for all $n$, and $\{s_n\}$ be the sequence of partial sums of $\sum a_n$. So we have $s_n \to +\infty$.

Let's suppose the following inequality is true for all natural $k$ and $n \ge N$: $$b_N > 1- \frac{s_n}{s_{n+k}}.$$ My question is: it's true that $1- \frac{s_n}{s_{n+k}}$ diverges?

Comment: What do you mean that 1-\frac{s_n}{s_n+k} diverges? Diverges as a sum?

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson The series of terms of the sequence $$1-\frac{s_n}{s_{n+k}}$$

Comment: Then trivially yes, you have by comparison test that $\sum b_n$ will diverge. I cannot see how to show that $1-\frac{s_n}{s_{n+k}}$ diverges though, that seems far more subtle.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking kekeke

Comment: You actually state it as a fact, "it's true that...."

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll correct that.

Comment: What is $b_n$ and why is it there?

Comment: I want to show that the right side diverges, so I can conclude that $\sum b_n$ diverges

Comment: Or, using that $\{ s_n \}$ diverges to somehow conclude divergence of $\sum b_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to monotony of $s_n$, we have $1-\frac{s_n}{s_{n+k}}\ge1-\frac{s_n}{s_{n+1}}$. It's well known that the infinite sum
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(1-\frac{s_n}{s_{n+1}}\right)$$ converges if and only if the infinite (telescoping) product $$\prod^\infty_{n=1}\frac{s_n}{s_{n+1}}$$ converges (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product), and that happens if and only if the sequence $s_n$ converges.
So your statement is true.